# Angular 2 and Symfony 3 (OAuth and API calls)

Tags: api, symfony, angular, authentication, oauth

I have a project in Angular 2.4.0 where I want to call endpoints from a Symfony 3 REST API. Both projects are launched locally. To get rid of CORS errors in Http calls in Angular, I set some proxy rules as follows :

```
{
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://myapi.dev:8000",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""},
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

The first step is the authentication with Google OAuth, so I open a new popup window (in my Angular project) :

```
window.open('api/connect/google', '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
```

Then I chose a Google account to authenticate with, then the API close the popup window automatically when successfully authenticated.

Then I call the API again to get the current logged-in user :

```
get(): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.get('api/user')
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error));
  }
```

The problem is that the API throws the following :

```
Request URL:http://localhost:2222/api/user
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:2222

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
cache-control:no-cache, private
connection:close
content-type:json
date:Wed, 22 Mar 2017 10:20:32 GMT
location:http://myapi.dev:8000/login
server:nginx/1.11.10
transfer-encoding:chunked
x-debug-token:128b90
x-debug-token-link:http://myapi.dev:8000/_profiler/128b90
x-powered-by:PHP/7.1.3

Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:PHPSESSID=18c73caec383e91904dfd239d1a95faa
Host:localhost:2222
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:2222/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

It seems the API **don't know I'm already authenticated** and tries to redirect me to the `/login` route for **every** other Http calls I want to make.

The API works as following :

1. **/login** is a twig page with a link to /connect/google (the Google OAuth)
2. **/connect/google** allows you to choose one Google Account to authenticate with
3. If you call any API endpoint without being authenticated, it redirects you to **/login**
4. If you're **authenticated**, you can call every API endpoint

If I try all above Angular Http calls directly into the browser (eg: http://myapi.dev:8000/connect/google, http://myapi.dev:8000/user) everything works well.

I really have no idea where this issue comes from.

Comment: Does you app runs on the same domain? (http://myapi.dev:8000)
Does your app run on file protocol? (`file:///your_project_path/index.html`)

Comment: @michail_w The API runs on a VM, here's my /etc/hosts file: 
`10.201.33.9 myapi.dev` and the angular2 runs on `http://localhost:2222/`

Answer (score 0):

As you said in comments, Angular app is hosted on `http://localhost:2222/`, but api is hosted on `http://myapi.dev:8000`. Those two origins are completely different. It means that when `myapi.dev` will begin session, set cookie, it will be unavailable on `localhost`. Browser is not allowed to send cookies from different origins (due to CORS). That's why api doesn't see your session id key.

Possible ways to overcome problem:

1. Store both apps (angular and api) on the same origin (it means same domain, same protocol, and same port) - it's the easiest way.
2. Catch session ID cookie value (just after it will be set) and store it inside sessionStorage. Next, create Angular's request interceptor which will add SESSION cookie to all requests which're going to `myapi.dev`

Comment: Thank you for these explanations! So even if I set a proxy (as shown above) to angular to access the API, it'll not work ? I don't understand because when I try to make a Http request to API the browser send `Cookie:PHPSESSID=18c73caec383e9190dklfj239d1a95faa` in the Request Headers (see above). Can you give me an example of how to make both coexist on the same domain ? The first option seems to be easier.

Comment: The question is if PHPSESSID cookie value is send again after first login? It should, based on your last comment. If not, I would dig into api code (proxy) instead.